# Type 'ClientAssertionCertificate' exists in both '...ActiveDirectory.Platform' & '....ActiveDirectory'

Tags: msbuild, nuget, csproj

I have a cproj which uses the method `ClientAssertionCertificate` from `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`. When I do a msbuild at the project level, I'm seeing this strange error.

> error CS0433: The type 'ClientAssertionCertificate' exists in both 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform, Version=3.12.0.827, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e3`

I'm sure that I'm referring only the PackageReference `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` and no references to any other package/assembly which has `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll`.

Please let me know if any of you are aware of this and can guide me on where in the code should I do the troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the issue. A project reference within my project was using a PackageReference to 'IpamAsrExports-master'. This package has the assembly "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll" included within. After I upgraded the package 'IpamAsrExports-master' to a newer version, it resolved the issue.